# Recover NTFS partition on a iPC

Tags: windows, mac, partitioning, ntfs, data-recovery

On my "PC" :

I installed iPC/Mac OS X (I created HFS+ partition during the installation process)
Next, I created a FAT32 GUID partion with Mac OS X Disk utility.
Then I installed Windows Vista on a new NTFS partion (created on Windows Vista installation)
I let some free space. (I thought I'll install GNU/Linux also)

I created a second NTFS partion on Windows Vista. (I never saw it on Mac OS with MacFUSE-NTFS-3g)

When I needed some more space on C:, I tried to mix the available free space with C: using a VistaPE liveCD. VistaPE said it will convert my disk to "Dynamic Disk", I didn't cared : I accepted. Unfortunately Windows didn't boot after.

Thanks to Test Write (runned from Vista PE) :
I recovered the HFS+ partition (Mac OS X can now boot), and the second Windows partition but C is not accessible and has still its old size...

On GNU/Linux Ubuntu Live CD : C: appears but can't be mounted
On Vista PE : C: appears as RAW format and can't be mounted too..

**Which (NTFS partition) recovering tool should I use?**

I think the C: data are still here but my disk partition table is altered.
With photorec it is possible to recover the file content without their name.

I tried to use Active@ Boot Disk (Live CD) but it didn't worked properly (it ends on a sort of Windows blue screen of death)

**How to restore my partition C: as it was before?**
In the case I sucess repairing that partition : 
how to add more free space without putting a so big disorder..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need decent undelete utility for Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/128786/need-decent-undelete-utility-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

You could try out some of the partition recovery tools on the Hiren's Boot CD: http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/